# Is there a Kerberos testing tool?

Tags: windows-server-2008, kerberos

I often use `openssl s_client` to test and debug SSL connections (to LDAPS or HTTPS services). It allows me to isolate the problem down to SSL, without anything getting in the way.

I want to do something similar with Kerberos. I would like to use a small test, which would show :

1. The initial machine logon (the computer account)
2. The initial AS request from the user requesting a service
3. The kerberos exchange of the user getting a ticket
4. (optional) the request being sent to the service

I can do steps 1, 2 and 3 if I run Wireshark on a KDC, but it is usually not an option. I can manage to capture steps 2, 3 and 4 if I monitor trafic on the client.

Is there tool that would allow me to capture the every Kerberos login steps starting with the computer account, without running Wireshark on the KDC ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you expect to see in Wireshark if you don't actually send the request.

Comment: The exchange with the KDC

Comment: So run Wireshark. Purge your tickets. Reauthenticate. Stop your Wireshark trace. Profit.

Comment: I read the question as being about a tool to initiate an authentication from the command line.

Comment: net stop netlogon & net start netlogon.  That will do it.

Comment: As Ryan indicated, after you purge the tickets, as soon as you attempt to connect to any resource that requires authentication, a ticket sequence occurs.  And the Kerberos parser in Wireshark is as good as it gets, its actually far superior to Microsoft Network Monitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll go ahead and submit my previous comments as an answer. I hope it's what the OP wanted.

As you already know, you can use klist.exe to purge your Kerberos tickets.

So fire up Wireshark and start a trace.  Then purge your Kerberos tickets.  Then in a command prompt, type `net stop netlogon & net start netlogon`. (Or do something like try to access a network file share.)  That will cause the computer to request new Kerberos tickets from the KDC/Domain Controller.  Now stop your Wireshark trace.  You have successfully captured a network trace containing the interaction between domain member and domain controller.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. It never occurred to me that I could restart the netlogon service. From server_A, I use `net view \\server_B` I get the trace I need.

Answer (score 3):

Update: this answer is *nix specific and the question is about windows. Leaving it in for future reference, just in case.

You can use:

- `kdestroy` to wipe out your old tickets
- `kinit` to request a TGT
- `kvno` to request a ticket for a service, e.g. `kvno host/$(hostname -f)`

Oh, and `klist` does not let you purge the cache. It shows what tickets you have obtained.

Comment: The question should be clearer, but the asker is talking about a Windows host (windows-server-2008 tag), not a Unix-like. Klist.exe certainly does allow you to purge the cache.

Comment: Haha, sorry, didn't notice the tag. I thought something doesn't add up.

Comment: Also: prefix any of these commands with `KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout` to get a more detailed log